# controlling windows with jna

Tags: java, jna

I would like to be able to bring certain windows to the foreground, e. g. Firefox, with JNA.

At the moment, I am doing this by using the findWindow and showWindow functions. The findWindow function expects the window title. But the problem with the title is that it changes. I may have 5 tabs of Firefox open, each with a different title.

What is the safest way to achieve this? Can I somehow use the name of the exe to get all of its windows?

Thanks for help and tips!